# Access elements of array within object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I have scraped this object using puppeteer but it contains more information than I actually need. How do I access "height" within "components"? I have been googling for a while and have not found a solution that works.

```
{
  "components": [{
    "height": "1.8",
    "period": 11,
    "trueDirection": 139,
    "compassDirection": "SE"
  }, {
    "height": "5.5",
    "period": 8,
    "trueDirection": 72,
    "compassDirection": "ENE"
  }, {
    "height": "1",
    "period": 13,
    "trueDirection": 207,
    "compassDirection": "SSW"
  }],
  "unit": "ft",
  "title": "2-3<small class=\"unit\">ft</small>\n",
  "fadedRating": 0,
  "solidRating": 1,
  "time": "Noon",
  "date": "Thu 14/02",
  "isBigWave": false
}
```

Comment: What's your current code to extract `height`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract an array containing all the `height` values, use `map` like so:

```js
const data = {
  "components": [{
    "height": "1.8",
    "period": 11,
    "trueDirection": 139,
    "compassDirection": "SE"
  }, {
    "height": "5.5",
    "period": 8,
    "trueDirection": 72,
    "compassDirection": "ENE"
  }, {
    "height": "1",
    "period": 13,
    "trueDirection": 207,
    "compassDirection": "SSW"
  }],
  "unit": "ft",
  "title": "2-3<small class=\"unit\">ft</small>\n",
  "fadedRating": 0,
  "solidRating": 1,
  "time": "Noon",
  "date": "Thu 14/02",
  "isBigWave": false
};

const heights = data.components.map(e => e.height);

console.log(heights);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I use .forEach to iterate through the components array then you can access each height easily.

```js
const obj = {
  "components": [{
    "height": "1.8",
    "period": 11,
    "trueDirection": 139,
    "compassDirection": "SE"
  }, {
    "height": "5.5",
    "period": 8,
    "trueDirection": 72,
    "compassDirection": "ENE"
  }, {
    "height": "1",
    "period": 13,
    "trueDirection": 207,
    "compassDirection": "SSW"
  }],
  "unit": "ft",
  "title": "2-3<small class='\\unit\\'>ft</small>\\n",
  "fadedRating": 0,
  "solidRating": 1,
  "time": "Noon",
  "date": "Thu 14/02",
  "isBigWave": false
}

obj.components.forEach(c => console.log(c.height))
```